# Jasmine testing ajax request after click()

Tags: jquery, ajax, testing, click, jasmine

I am trying to test an ajax call after a click event using jasmine. I have tried a bunch of different things to get click to be recognized but cannot manage to get the the ajax to fire.

Here is my test file:

```
# use require to load any .js file available to the asset pipeline
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery.ui.all
#= require jquery.scrollTo.min
#= require application/save_search

setUpHTMLFixture = ->
  loadFixtures "home_page"

describe "save_search", ->
  beforeEach ->
    setUpHTMLFixture()

  it "should get the list of friends and insert it in the page", ->
    print $("#save-search")
    spyOn jQuery, "ajax"
    $("#save-search").click()
    print $("#save-search")
    jQuery.ajax.mostRecentCall.args[0].success "Something"
    expect($("#save-search").length).toBe 2
```

My code:

```
jQuery ->

  $("#save-search").click ->
    draggables = undefined
    draggables = {}
    jQuery.each jQuery(".ui-draggable"), (index, draggable) ->
      child = undefined
      parentId = undefined
      classes = undefined
      left = undefined
      offset = undefined
      top = undefined
      value = undefined
      draggable = jQuery(this)
      parentId = draggable.parent().attr("id")
      child = draggable.children()
      value = child.val()
      classes = draggable.attr("class").replace(/ui-draggable|down|cloner|\s/g, "")
      key = classes + index
      offset = draggable.offset()
      left = offset.left
      top = offset.top
      draggables[key] =
        value: value
        left: left
        top: top
        parent_id: parentId

    draggables["name"] = $("#search-name").val()

    $.ajax
      type: "POST"
      url: "/searches/save_search"
      data:
        draggables: JSON.stringify(draggables)

      dataType: "json"
      success: (msg) ->
        alert "Data Saved: " + msg

      false
```

My fixture:

```
<a id="save-search">Save Search</a>

<div class="ui-draggable">some stuff</div>

<div class="ui-draggable">some stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andreas Koberle's answer I got it working.

Here is the code:

```
window.addEvent = ->
  $("#save-search").click ->
     # Do stuff like define value here...

    $.ajax
      type: "POST"
      url: "/your/url/here"
      data:
        key: value

      dataType: "json"
      success: (msg) ->
        alert "Your message here"

      false

jQuery -> addEvent()
```

Here is the test:

```
setUpHTMLFixture = ->
  loadFixtures "your_fixture"

describe "save_search", ->
  beforeEach ->
    setUpHTMLFixture()

  it "should call ajax with your url", ->
    addEvent()
    spyOn jQuery, "ajax"
    $("#save-search").click()
    expect($.ajax.mostRecentCall.args[0]["url"]).toEqual("/your/url/here")
```

The fixture: your_fixture.html

```
<a id="save-search">Save Search</a>

<div class="ui-draggable">some stuff</div>

<div class="ui-draggable">some stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you bind the event to an element that does not exists when the script is running cause it will be run before the `setUpHTMLFixture` could create the html. You have to refactor your code so you can call a function in the test that will add the binding after the fixture was created.

```
window.addEvent = ->
  $("#save-search").click ->
    draggables = undefined
    draggables = {}
    jQuery.each jQuery(".ui-draggable"), (index, draggable) ->
      child = undefined
      parentId = undefined
      classes = undefined
      left = undefined
      offset = undefined
      top = undefined
      value = undefined
      draggable = jQuery(this)
      parentId = draggable.parent().attr("id")
      child = draggable.children()
      value = child.val()
      classes = draggable.attr("class").replace(/ui-draggable|down|cloner|\s/g, "")
      key = classes + index
      offset = draggable.offset()
      left = offset.left
      top = offset.top
      draggables[key] =
        value: value
        left: left
        top: top
        parent_id: parentId

    draggables["name"] = $("#search-name").val()

    $.ajax
      type: "POST"
      url: "/searches/save_search"
      data:
        draggables: JSON.stringify(draggables)

      dataType: "json"
      success: (msg) ->
        alert "Data Saved: " + msg

      false

jQuery ->  addEvent
```

and in your test

```
setUpHTMLFixture = ->
  loadFixtures "home_page"

describe "save_search", ->
  beforeEach ->
    setUpHTMLFixture()

  it "should get the list of friends and insert it in the page", ->
    addEvent()
    print $("#save-search")
    spyOn jQuery, "ajax"
    $("#save-search").click()
    print $("#save-search")
    jQuery.ajax.mostRecentCall.args[0].success "Something"
    expect($("#save-search").length).toBe 2
```

Comment: This made the test pass.  Thank you.  The only problem is now the click binding is not working in the live app.

Comment: Okay.  I figured it out.  You need to add a () to add event at the end of the code.

jQuery ->  addEvent()